# how to fix Missing argument 4 for App\Http\Controllers\FilesController::saveUploads() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have file attachment form like following form actions.

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                    method="post"
                                    action=" route('projects.files', ['taskId'=>$task->id])">
            <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('file_name') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                <input type="file" name="file_name" class="form-control" id="file_name">
                @if ($errors->has('file_name'))
                    <span class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('file_name') }}</span>
                @endif
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Add Files</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        </form>
```

and My FileController is this

```
public function uploadAttachments(Request $request,$id)
    {
       $this->validate($request, [
            'file_name'     => 'required|mimes:jpeg,bmp,png,pdf|between:1,7000',
        ]);

        $filename     = $request->file('file_name')->getRealPath();
        Cloudder::upload($filename, null);
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
        $fileUrl = Cloudder::show(Cloudder::getPublicId(), ["width" => $width, "height" => $height]);
        $this->saveUploads($request, $fileUrl, $id);//line 36
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Your Attachment has been uploaded Successfully');
    }

    private function saveUploads(Request $request, $fileUrl, $id,$taskId) //line 43
    {
        $file = new File;
        $file->file_name  = $request->file('file_name')->getClientOriginalName();
        $file->file_url   = $fileUrl;
        $file->project_id = $id;
        $file->task_id = $taskId;
        $file->save();

    }
```

but when I am going to attach files I got following errors.

```
 ErrorException in FilesController.php line 43: Missing argument 4 for App\Http\Controllers\FilesController::saveUploads(), called in C:\Users\John\Desktop\ddd\app\Http\Controllers\FilesController.php on line 36 and defined
```

how can fix this problem?

Comment: You are sending `['taskId'=>$task->id]` in form action, but `uploadAttachments` has `$id` as parameter. You are using `$id` in `saveUploads` as `project_id`. Where `project_id` is coming from?

Comment: actually I have project_id in My form action **action=" route('projects.files', ['projectId'=>$project->id,'taskId'=>$task->id])">**

Comment: may I should change variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this you have to send `$taskId` to the Controller and then to `saveUploads` method. Try something like this:

View:

```
<form class="form-vertical" role="form"
                                    enctype="multipart/form-data"
                                    method="post"
                                    action=" route('projects.files', 
                                           ['projectId' => $project->id, 
                                           'taskId'=>$task->id])">
```

Controller:

```
public function uploadAttachments(Request $request, $projectId, $taskId)
{ 
    (...)
    $this->saveUploads($request, $fileUrl, $projectId, $taskId);
```

This should work

Comment: yes it is working but little bit problem when I sent $taskId to the table it is saved as this **route('projects.files', ['taskId'=>$task->id** how to fix this?

Comment: Does it have a string in $taskId?

Comment: what did you mean **a string**

Comment: $taskId has `route('projects.files', ['taskId'=>$task->id` as its content?

Comment: This seems to be a mistake with quotes (" and '). Check if there is any problem with them in the form action.

Comment: is this My route problem **Route::post('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
     'uses' => 'FilesController@uploadAttachments',
     'as'   => 'projects.files',
     'middleware' => ['auth']
]);**

Comment: Try to use the same names in all the files. For example: change `{ projects}` to `{projectId}` and check if you find the issue. After that, you can fix other problems.